# Sorting list of objects using two different properties in java

Tags: list, sorting, object, properties

```
public class Customer {
    String loanNumber;
    Date acctStartDate;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

I have List objects and want to sort in asc order by `acctStartDate` and then `loanNumber`.

If two accounts started on same day i.e. two objects have same acctStartDate then it should use loanNumber to sort further

```
So the priority is 
First : acctStartDate
Second : loanNumber
```

Here the loanNumber is String. Someone pls help me :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CompareToBuilder` class from Apache Commons library and add multiple sorting constraints by calling append() on it. Try the below code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.CompareToBuilder;

....

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Customer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer obj1, Customer obj2) {
        return new CompareToBuilder().append(obj1.acctStartDate, obj2.acctStartDate)
                .append(obj1.loanNumber, obj2.loanNumber).toComparison();
    }
});
```